# Parallel.Foreach exceptions and cancel

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach, cancellation

I have tried to find out how exceptions and cancel work for `Parallel.Foreach`. All examples seems to deal with Tasks.

What happens on an exception in `Parallel.Foreach`?

- Do I wrap the entire loop in try/catch (`AggregateException`)?
- Will all other tasks in the loop, even tasks not started yet, run to completion before the exception is caught?

Same questions for `CancellationToken`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In short, exception in each loop is aggregated and presented under `AggregateException`. Whenever exception occurs, loops that are started are allowed to complete but no further loops will be started. `ForEach` does have many [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach#overloads) that allow one to have local init & finally blocks and body action also takes [ParallelLoopState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate) that loop body code can use to check for exception occurrence on another loop and then break it self cooperatively if needed.

See [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/exiting-from-parallel-loops-early/) that provides additional information

Comment: Link is broken.